# How can I get my Bluetooth Devices Service UUID? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uuid, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I'm trying to make a basic connection with a bluetooth body weight scale that I own. 
The problem is that I am unable to find the UUID in order to connect to the device.

I've reached out to the manufacture to see if they could provide the UUID, which they said was "FFF0"

When I set the ScanForPeripherals function UUID to FFF0 my app logs "central.state is.poweredOn" however I am unable to find the device.

I know the device exists because when I use "centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices:nil) It locates it.

Here are some screenshots  and my code. I couldn't find any information on here about this particular situation, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not sure if they gave me the wrong UUID or if it's something I'm doing on my end.
If so, what do I need to do to find my particular device rather than all the devices around me.

Below you can see where I scan for peripherals. The commented code is when I set the UUID. And above that is the same code with UUID set to nil.

```
extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

        switch central.state {         
        case .unknown:
            print("central.state is .unknown")
        case .resetting:
            print("central.state is .resetting")
        case .unsupported:
            print("central.state is .unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("central.state is .unauthorized")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("central.state is .poweredOff")
        case .poweredOn:
            print("central.state is .poweredOn")
            centralManager.scanForsPeripherals(withServices:nil)

            //SET CBUUID to FFF0
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices:[bodyScaleServiceCBUUID])

        }
    }
```

When I set to nil. The console shows my device & all other devices advertising

When I set UUID to FFF0 I just get `central.state is .poweredOn` and no devices are found.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Can you please mention the name of the weight scale (model, manufacturer) you want to test you code with ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [link](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/) for UUID for the Bluetooth Services.

In this I could find that UUID for Weight Scale is 0x181D. Please try this,

```
let weightScaleServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x181D")
```

Comment: Hey thanks Anusha, for providing the link. I tried that UUID and same thing, unfortunately  wasn’t able to find the peripheral.

Comment: Did you try the UUID given by the manufacturer with this format, 0xFFF0?